# Get blog posts information from another page on the site (they have the same classes, needs to regard to order)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okey, so I have a site on Weebly.com. They have an inbuilt blog service that creates random main div id’s for each post. The classes for title, date and content remain the same throughout though. So I guess the script needs to take into considaration the order of the information it gets.

**So how can I get the information in those classes to be displayed on my home page (in proper order)?**

---

### What I’m looking for:

- **Get blog titles with corresponding link**
- **Get blog dates**
- **Get blog contents** (*with a show limit of a certain amount of characters*)
- **The information get in correct order** (*Post 1: blog title 1, blog date 1, content 1 – Post 2: blog title 2, blog date 2, contant 2 and so on…*)
- **Set the amount of blog post extractions displayed on the home page**

If someone out there knows how to do this, big thanks!

---

**HTML code on the blog page** ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8hL3/2/))

```
<div id='wsite-content'>

    <!-- POST 1 -->

    <div id='blog-post-984693871936925110' class='blog-post'>
        <div class='blog-header'>
             <h2 class='blog-title'><a href='/loremipsum1.html' class='blog-title-link' class='blog-link'>Lorem ipsum 1</a></h2> 
            <p class='blog-date'><span class='date-text'>03/16/2014</span></p>
            <!-- 984693871936925110 -->
        </div>
        <div class='blog-separator'>&nbsp;</div>
        <div class='blog-content'>
            <div class="paragraph" style="text-align:left;">Lorem ipsum text content 2.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- POST 2 -->

    <div id='blog-post-714981109579736638' class='blog-post'>
        <div class='blog-header'>
             <h2 class='blog-title'><a href='/loremipsum2.html' class='blog-title-link' class='blog-link'>Lorem ipsum 2</a></h2> 
            <p class='blog-date'><span class='date-text'>03/16/2014</span></p>
            <!-- 714981109579736638 -->
        </div>
        <div class='blog-separator'>&nbsp;</div>
        <div class='blog-content'>
            <div class="paragraph" style="text-align:left;">Lorem ipsum text content 2.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- POST 3 -->

    <div id='blog-post-867134434816472113' class='blog-post'>
        <div class='blog-header'>
             <h2 class='blog-title'><a href='/loremipsum3.html' class='blog-title-link' class='blog-link'>Lorem ipsum 3</a></h2> 
            <p class='blog-date'><span class='date-text'>03/16/2014</span></p>
            <!-- 867134434816472113 -->
        </div>
        <div class='blog-separator'>&nbsp;</div>
        <div class='blog-content'>
            <div class="paragraph" style="text-align:left;">Lorem ipsum text content 3.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  var numOfPosts= 1;
  $('.blog-post').each(function(){
   if(numOfPosts < 10) {        
         var title = $(this).find('.blog-title').html();
         var date  = $(this).find('.blog-date').html();
         var contents  = $(this).find('.blog-content').html();
         numOfPosts++;
     }
 });
});
```

This will extract all the data you need only for the first 10 posts.

Comment: Looks realy good, though I cant get it to work. The blog posts are on a page called nyheter.html and I want it on the index.html. And saw that you have a '.blog-post', is it not needed to add that all '.blog-post-xxxxxxxxxxxx...' are taken into considaration (since thay are random each post)? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your html question but it sounds like JS isn't your answer. You may be better of creating your own template page and filtering results through there (depending on your CMS / blog service). As for the .blog-post, this is filtering against the class="blog-post" not the id